# Add multiple UILabels below each other with each label having variable lines

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a view and I want to and a set of labels to it, but the number of labels and the length of text of each label varies.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 50)];
label.text = @"Varying text length here";
label.numberOfLines = 0;
[label sizeToFit];
[[self view] addSubview:label];
```

What's the simplest way to add another label programmatically beneath this label at a set distance of 25 when the label could have between 1-4 lines?

Comment: Why zero? That way becomes empty.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri wrong, numberOfLines = 0 means entirely variable number of lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
CGFloat offset = 25.0f;

CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(10, 100, 30, 50);

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame1];
label.text = @"Varying text length here";
label.numberOfLines = 0;
[label sizeToFit];
[[self view] addSubview:label];

CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(10,
                           label.frame.origin.y + label.frame.size.height + offset,
                           300,
                           50);

UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame2];
label2.text = @"Varying text length here";
label2.numberOfLines = 0;
[label2 sizeToFit];
[[self view] addSubview:label2];
```

Set the next label's frame based on the previous label's frame + 25

Comment: There are two readability optimizations you could do here. Most simply, you can replace `label.frame.origin.y + label.frame.size.height` with `CGRectGetMaxY(label.frame)` which is more semantic and shorter. Second, since your width and height are being adjusted by `sizeToFit` anyway, you could consider using `CGRectOffset(label.frame, 0, CGRectGetHeight(label.frame)+offset)` instead of using `CGRectMake` for the second label (this means you don't have to repeat hard-coded values like the `x` position).

Answer (score 1):

Give a look to [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UICollectionViewFlowLayout). It handles a grid of elements, that's right what you want.

Change the value of this property:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGSize itemSize;
```

To specify the size of each item (in your case would be 300,50). Also this one:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat minimumLineSpacing;
```

To handle the gap between items.